# Needs Help To Troubleshoot Fetching Single Document From Firebase Database As Detailed Page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

[image]

I'm try to get single document as detail information from Firebase database under collection "books", however my array method map does not recognize as function due to the render produce "undefined". Somehow render again and produce the object value in log. I posted the screenshot of the log above, hoping somebody help me out, thanks!!!!!

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import firebase from '../config/fbConfig'

const BookDetails = (props) => {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]) 
        useEffect(() => {
            const db = firebase.firestore()
            const id = props.match.params.id
            var docRef = db.collection("books").doc(id);
                docRef.get().then(doc => {
                    if(doc.exists){
                        const data = doc.data()
                        console.log("Document data:", data)
                        setBooks(data)
                    }else {
                        console.log("No such document!");
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                })
        }, [])
               console.log('this log is before return', books.title)
    return (
        
        <div className="book_details">
            <Link to="/"><h2>Home</h2></Link>     
                {console.log("this log is in the return method", books.title)}
            <h1>The Summary Of the Book </h1>
                {books.map( book => <ul key = "book.id" >
                    <li>Book Title: {book.title}</li>
                    <li>Book Author: {book.author}</li>
                    <li>Book Summery: {book.brief}</li>
                </ul>)}
        </div>
    )
}



export default BookDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are testing whether `books` is undefined and only call the map function if it is defined (i.e. `{books && books.map( [...] )}`), the problem must lie somewhere else.

You are fetching a single document from your Firebase database. Therefore, the returned data will not be an array but an object which does not have the `map` function in its prototype. You can verify this from your console logs.

Your component renders twice because you are changing its state inside the `useEffect` via `setBooks(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = firebase.firestore()
const id = props.match.params.id
```

First of all move these lines inside of useEffect.

Coming to the problem

You are fetching a single doc(object) from firebase and saving it in a state which is an array. Change your useState to

```
const \[book, setBook\] = useState(undefined) // or useState({})
```

Change your return to

```
return (
        
        <div className="book_details">
            <Link to="/"><h2>Home</h2></Link>     
                {console.log("this log is in the return method", books.title)}
            <h1>The Summary Of the Book </h1>
                 {book && <div key={book.id}> {book.brief} </div>}

        </div>
    )
```

// or `{Object.keys(book).length !== 0 && <div key={book.id}> {book.brief} </div>}`
if you have used empty object in useState.